# Why I obtain this exception when I try to insert records by different methods in a single transaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, transactions

I have the following problem:

I had an old method that performed the insertion in 3 tables (named **Cpe**, **CpeVendor** and **CpeProduct** respecting the referential integrity constraints.

This method simply execute 3 insert query into its body: first the record into **CpeVendor** and **CpeProduct** and then **Cpe** with the reference to the previous 2 records. The 3 insert was in a transaction.

Now I have refactored this method in this way:

I have create 2 private method that insert the record into **CpeVendor** and **CpeProduct** and I call them into the main insert method but now I obtain an exception. This is my code:

```
    public long insert(DataModel.CPE.CPE cpe)
    {
        _strSQL = "";
        string strSQLParametri = "";
        string query = "";

        long CpeVendorId, CpeProductId;

        long newId;

        try
        {
            _transactionBegin();

            if (cpe.Cpe == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
            command = _connection.CreateCommand();

            // Se il vendor non è presente nella tabella CpeVendor:
            if (cpe.VendorId == -1)         
            {
                CpeVendorId = this.insertCpeVendor(cpe.Vendor);   
            }

            // Se il product non è presente nella tabella CpeProduct:
            if (cpe.ProductId == -1)         
            {
                cpe.ProductId = this.insertCpeProduct(cpe.Product);
            }

            #region INSERIMENTO DEL CPE

            _strSQL = "INSERT INTO Cpe ( DateAdded,  [Cpe] ";
            strSQLParametri = " VALUES ( GETDATE(), @CPE ";
            addParameter(command, "@CPE ", cpe.Cpe);


            // [SourceId] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.SourceId != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[SourceId] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @SOURCEID ";
                addParameter(command, "@SOURCEID ", cpe.SourceId);
            }

            // [vendor_id] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.VendorId != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[vendor_id] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @VENDORID ";
                addParameter(command, "@VENDORID ", cpe.VendorId);
            }

            // [Title] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.Title != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[Title] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @TITLE ";
                addParameter(command, "@TITLE ", cpe.Title);
            }

            // [part] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.Part != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[part] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @PART ";
                addParameter(command, "@PART ", cpe.Part.ToString().ToLower().Substring(0,1));
            }

            // [product_id] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.ProductId != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[product_id] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @PRODUCTID";
                addParameter(command, "@PRODUCTID ", cpe.ProductId);
            }

            // [version] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.Version != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[version] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @VERSION";
                addParameter(command, "@VERSION ", cpe.Version);
            }

            // [revision] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.Revision != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[revision] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @REVISION";
                addParameter(command, "@REVISION ", cpe.Revision);
            }

            // [edition] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.Edition != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[edition] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @EDITION";
                addParameter(command, "@EDITION ", cpe.Edition);
            }

            // [language] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.Language != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[language] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @LANGUAGE";
                addParameter(command, "@LANGUAGE ", cpe.Language);
            }

            // [software_edition] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.SoftwareEdition != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[software_edition] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @SOFTWAREEDITION";
                addParameter(command, "@SOFTWAREEDITION ", cpe.SoftwareEdition);
            }

            // [target_software] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.TargetSoftware != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[target_software] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @TARGETSOFTWARE";
                addParameter(command, "@TARGETSOFTWARE ", cpe.TargetSoftware);
            }

            // [target_hardware] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.TargetHardware != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[target_hardware] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @TARGETHARDWARE";
                addParameter(command, "@TARGETHARDWARE ", cpe.TargetHardware);
            }

            // [other] insertion on the DB:
            if (cpe.Other != null)
            {
                _strSQL += ",[other] ";
                strSQLParametri += ", @OTHER";
                addParameter(command, "@OTHER ", cpe.Other);
            }

            query = _strSQL + " ) " + strSQLParametri + " );";
            command.CommandText = query;
            _executeNoQuery(command);

            newId = _getIdentity();
            //Debug.WriteLine("Id: " + newId);
            #endregion

            _transactionCommit();

            return newId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            _transactionRollback();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private long insertCpeVendor(String vendorName){
        System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
        command = _connection.CreateCommand();
        string strSQLParametri = "";
        string query = "";
        long CpeVendorId = -1;

        // [nome] insertion on the DB:
        if (vendorName != null)
        {
            _strSQL = "INSERT INTO CpeVendor ( [nome] ";
            strSQLParametri = " VALUES (@VENDORNAME ";
            addParameter(command, "@VENDORNAME ", vendorName);

            // [date_added] insertion on the DB:
            _strSQL += ",[date_added] ";
            strSQLParametri += ", GETDATE() ";

            query = _strSQL + " ) " + strSQLParametri + " );";
            command.CommandText = query;
            _executeNoQuery(command);

            CpeVendorId = _getIdentity();
            Debug.WriteLine("PK della tabella CpeVendorId: " + CpeVendorId);
        }
        return CpeVendorId;
    }

    private long insertCpeProduct(String productName)
    {
        System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
        command = _connection.CreateCommand();
        string strSQLParametri = "";
        string query = "";
        long CpeProductId = -1;

        // [nome] insertion on the DB:
        if (productName != null)
        {
            _strSQL = "INSERT INTO CpeProduct ( [nome] ";
            strSQLParametri = " VALUES (@PRODUCTNAME ";
            addParameter(command, "@PRODUCTNAME ", productName);


            // [date_added] insertion on the DB:
            _strSQL += ",[date_added] ";
            strSQLParametri += ", GETDATE() ";

            query = _strSQL + " ) " + strSQLParametri + " );";
            command.CommandText = query;
            _executeNoQuery(command);

            CpeProductId = _getIdentity();
            Debug.WriteLine("PK della tabella CpeProductId: " + CpeProductId);
        }
        return CpeProductId;
    }
```

The problem is that now when it execute the **executeNoQuery** for the main **insert()** method the following exception is launched:

```
{"ExecuteNonQuery terminato con errori. \r\nINSERT INTO Cpe ( DateAdded,  [Cpe] ,[SourceId] ,[vendor_id] ,[Title] ,[part] ,[product_id] ,[version]  )  VALUES ( GETDATE(), @CPE , @SOURCEID , @VENDORID , @TITLE , @PART , @PRODUCTID, @VERSION );\r\nThe INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_Cpe_CpeVendor\". The conflict occurred in database \"EarlyWarningsV2\", table \"dbo.CpeVendor\", column 'id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}    System.Exception {MyManagerCSharp.MyException}
```

It seems to me (but it could be wrong) that if I execute the insert into the **CpeVendor** and **CpeProduct** tables by different private methods is as these inserts are not in the same transaction of the insert executed in the main insert() method.

Is it the problem or what? What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

What type of transactions are you using? ADO.NET transactions? `TransactionScope`?

If ADO.NET: you haven't attached the transaction to the command (`command.Transaction = ...`)

If `TransactionScope`: the connection was open **before** the transaction started, so it will not enlist; automatic enlist only occurs for connections opened inside the ambient transaction

In either case, I would say that `_transactionBegin();` / `_transactionRollback();` etc (that presumably use fields) is a very bad way of scoping the transactions. But hard to say without more context.